# LEFT JOIN ON NULL Key Values Combined with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, join, group-by, teradata

I'm using Teradata SQL and I wrote the following query (pay attention at the LEFT JOIN)

```
SELECT
    key1,
    secondvalue,
    count(DISTINCT firstvalue)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        t1.val AS firstvalue,
        t1.key1,
        t2.val AS secondvalue
        
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.key1 = t1.key1 AND t1.key2 = t2.key2 AND t1.key3 = t2.key3
) AS Testcase
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Some entries for t1.key2 und t1.key3 (of the left sided table) are NULL. When that's the case, the rows are not showing in the result, why? Is that Teradata specific, I would expect a LEFT JOIN to show rows with NULL values.

If I for example choose to reduce the LEFT JOIN statement to

```
SELECT
    key1,
    secondvalue,
    count(DISTINCT firstvalue)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        t1.val AS firstvalue,
        t1.key1,
        t2.val AS secondvalue
        
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.key1 = t1.key1
) AS Testcase
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

More distinct values for key1 are showing up, which shouldn't be the case, right? I'd want to see all distinct values for key1, even when then key2 and key3 are NULL. If not, I want to see the specific value from the second table.

I really don't want to map the NULL values to another value first.

Comment: Are you aware that your join predicate has a condition that is always true? `t1.key1 = t1.key1` `t1.key1` will always match `t1.key1`. I think you meant `t2.key1 = t1.key1`?

Comment: What columns are 1 & 2 in Testcase? What columns of what table do you think they refer to? What is your justification referencing authoritative documentation for "shouldn't be the case"? (We can expect your expectations are wrong, not the DBMS. Moreover how do we address your expectations if you don't say what they are? The answer to "why" is, because that's how the language is defined; don't ask for yet another presentation.) [mre] PS LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some entries for t1.key2 und t1.key3 (of the left sided table) are NULL. When that's the case, the rows are not showing in the result, why?

Likely because `group by` and `distinct` will group all nulls together. It is true that in SQL, `null` does not necessarily equal `null`, but I believe that from a distinct and group by perspective, `nulls` are considered identical.

> I would expect a LEFT JOIN to show rows with NULL values.

I've never tried a left outer join where null is on the left side. I can't say whether the join would emit a result for such a row, but I can tell you that it wouldn't match an equi-join because `null` does not equal `null`. Are you looking for a full outer join?

> `LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.key1 = t1.key1`

This predicate will match every row where `t1.key1 is not null`, which is almost a Cartesian product. That is why your count is so much larger.

I think you want

`LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.key1 = t2.key1`

> I'd want to see all distinct values for key1, even when then key2 and key3 are NULL

Overall, I think what you want is

```
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.key1 = t2.key1 AND coalesce(t1.key2, -1) = coalesce(t2.key2, -1) AND coalesce(t1.key3, -1) = coalesce(t2.key3, -1)
```

You want the second argument to `coalesce` to be a syntactically valid value of whatever type `key2` and `key3` are, but be a value that is not valid in your usage of it (otherwise, we'd joining rows where we have `-1` on one side and `null` on the other.

Comment: Instead of COALESCE it's recommended (in Teradata) to use `...AND (t1.key2 = t2.key2 OR t1.key2 IS NULL AND t2.key2 IS NULL) AND...`. No need to find an unused value for coalesce and might be more performant, too.

Comment: mh, weirdly your recommendation (coalesce) and @dnoeth do not work. they are missing like 3 primary key (key1) values. I don't get it. I have to look further in this case tomorrow.

Comment: After carefully reanalizing the data, I came to the conclusion, that your solution matches my needs. Thank you!